# First line integer n as input, next line n number as input separated by space

Tags: python, python-3.x

1.First line an integer N as input

2.second line N numbers of integer as input separated by space

Example 1

```
4

11 22 44 12
```

Example 2

```
3

1 9 11
```

Tried this

```
l=[map(int,input().split()) for i in range(n)]
```

Taking input in separate line

Actual Output

```
[map,map,map,map]
```

Excepted output

```
[11,22,44,12]
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about taking `n` first, you can just take an input string and split on spaces like this

```
l = [int(i) for i in input().split(" ")]
```

then `n` is the length of that list

```
n = len(l)
```

If you do want to take `n` first, to make sure you only take a certain length list, you can do something like

```
n = int(input())
l_input = input()
l = [int(i) for i in l_input.split(" ")]

assert len(l) == n, "list is not of correct length"
```